# Do Google Custom Search API Autocomplete feature increases the query limit?

Tags: autocomplete, google-custom-search, google-search-api

Am using Google Custom Search API with 2000 queries/day. Am planning to enable Autocomplete feature for the Custom Search. Do autocomplete results increases the queries count or is this not consider in queries count?

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete feature doesn't count towards your daily limit. On the other hand, when you make a query with more than 10 results and you want to paginate over them, every pagination request counts towards your daily limit.